# php delete the value from the database and make other unchanged

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, checkbox

I am really a newbie in php and mysql. So for learning I am doing a small project.
The target of the project is like this.I have a database with id,name,public name attributes. Now I have to fetch all the values of public name and show them in a check-boxes each. Now when someone selects any checkbox and click save button then that value should come in a container in a list format.For that I have predefined database named as ps_attribute_group, the database has values like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ia_attribute_group` (
  `id_attribute_group` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `public_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ia_attribute_group`,`id_lang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ia_attribute_group` (`id_attribute_group`, `name`, `public_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Disk space', 'Disk space'),
(2, 'Color', 'Color'),
(3, 'ICU', 'Processor'),
(4,  'color', 'color');
```

Now my work is to get all the name from the database in a list with checkbox and under the list I will have my save button. So when I will select any checkbox and click on save then this will save in another database named as ia_attribute_names

So for that I have done a database ia_attribute_names like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ia_attribute_names` (
  `attribute_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So from starting I have my database connection

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = 'database_name';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

As I need the public_name from the database ia_attribute_group inside my form with all checkboxes. I have made this code.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT `public_name` FROM `ia_attribute_group`") or die (mysql_error());?>
  <form id="formID" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php 
      while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
        foreach($results as $result) { 
          echo '<input type="checkbox" name="attribute[]"  value="'.$result.'"/>';
          echo $result.'<br />';
        }
      }
?>
<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="save"/>
</form>
```

This one is fetching all the public name and converting them into checkboxes.Now in the form you can see the submit button. So when someone clicks this after selecting checkbox it will save the values to the database ia_attribute_names.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `ia_attribute_names`(`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES ('', '".$attribute_values."')";
  $insert = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query) or die(mysqli_error());
  if($insert) {
    echo 'success';
  }
  else {
    echo 'error';
  }
}
```

Now from the database ia_attribute_names I will fetch the  data like all of them are in list. So for that I have my code like this

```
<div id="container">
<?php
  $attribute_name = @$_POST['attribute'];
  $attribute_values= @implode(',', $_POST['attribute']);
  $sql_query = "SELECT `attribute_name` FROM `ia_attribute_names` ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
  $attributes_name = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query );
  $list_names = mysqli_fetch_array($attributes_name);
    //echo $list_names['attribute_name'];
    $resultArr = explode(",",$list_names['attribute_name']);
    print_r($resultArr);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($resultArr as $atributeValue){
    $listId = str_replace(' ','',$atributeValue);
    ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $listId; ?>"><?php echo $atributeValue; ?> <a href="" onClick="deleteAttribute();  return false;">Delete</a> </li>

   <?php }
?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Now upto this point I have done all the fetch and data. But I am relly confuse with delete function. As you can see inside list I have a tags. So when someone clicks on delete then the selected list should be delete from the list and also from the database.
Lets say I have 3 lists Disk Space, Color and Processor. If someone clicks on Color then the color will be removed from both frontend and backend. The rest two should be unchanged. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks.
There may be some bugs in the code, as I am learning now. So I will be really happy if you make corrections to the bugs.

**Update**
You can see I am storing the values as text format. So how can I delete the selected text from the database text and keep other text unchanged?

**NOTE**
The public name values should not be constant in numbers. Here I have used only 3 (Disk Space, Color, Processor). It may vary.

Comment: Can you break down your question in necessary parts only? Describe your problem only. What did your tried to delete?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give class to `li` element. You can use it like;

```
<li id="<?php echo $listId; ?>"><?php echo $atributeValue; ?> <a href="" onClick="deleteAttribute(<?php echo $listId; ?>);  return false;">Delete</a> </li>
```

**Jquery:**

```
function deleteAttribute(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "your_domain/delete",
        type: "POST",
        data : "id=" + id,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
                //data - response from server. Check response result
                alert(data);
                $("#" + id).remove();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("Delete error!")
        }
    });

}
```

In order to use `attribute_id`;

Update this;

```
$sql_query = "SELECT `attribute_name` FROM `ia_attribute_names` ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

to

```
$sql_query = "SELECT `attribute_id`,`attribute_name` FROM `ia_attribute_names` ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

and use `attribute_id` in your `li`, and `href`. Finally, it becomes;

```
<div id="container">
<?php
  $attribute_name = @$_POST['attribute'];
  $attribute_values= @implode(',', $_POST['attribute']);
  $sql_query = "SELECT `attribute_name` FROM `ia_attribute_names` ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query );
  echo '<ul>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $row['attribute_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['attribute_name']; ?> <a href="" onClick="deleteAttribute($row['attribute_id'];);  return false;">Delete</a> </li>

   <?php }
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Huseyein BABAL thanks for the reply. But how can I delete the matching text from the database. As u can see I am storing the values into the database as text.

Comment: You don't need to use text. Even it is dangerous to delete by text. You are also inserting `attribute_id` also I think it is `auto_increment`. You can put `attribute_id` to html and you can use that id while deleting

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use attribute_id in your select statement and use it in your html

Comment: in jQuery alert(data) it is showing blank. I mean no id can be seen in alertbox.

Comment: Could you please add your php file that contyains delete functionalities to your question? You need to return something at the end of delete operation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45778/discussion-between-jagdish-and-huseyin-babal)